# Prepend a div inside another as first child

Tags: javascript, html

I need to move a `<div>` inside another as a first child. Suppose, I have a `<div class="wrap">` within its parent `<div id="wpbody-content">`. Now, I need to attach a `<div>` inside the `<div class="wrap">` as a first child. Here is my code that I tried:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.className = 'row';
  div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="" />\
    <input type="text" name="value" value="" />\
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" /> Checked? </label>\
    <input type="button" value="-" >';
  document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].insertBefore(div, document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap").firstChild);
});
```

But it appends the `<div>` as the last child.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array.. did you forget a [0] before the firstChild bit? BTW this isn't how I'd write it... your lines are too long, you should be able to simplify at least with an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function that arranges append like this function `prependEle(parent, child);`

See the very bottom of `js` code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'row';
    
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="" />\
        <input type="text" name="value" value="" />\
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" /> Checked? </label>\
        <input type="button" value="-" >';
    var wp = document.getElementById("wpbody-content");
    var firstWrap = wp.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0];
    prependEle(firstWrap, div);
});

function prependEle(parent, child) {
  parent.insertBefore(child, parent.firstChild);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to get first element by doing `[0]` when you are inserting the element before first child.

```
  document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].insertBefore(div, document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].firstChild);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------you forgot to do this---^-----
```

**Improve version**

```
var wrapDiv = document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0]; 
wrapDiv.insertBefore(div, wrapDiv.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node.insertBefore to accompolish it. Here is a the code and a demo

HTML

```
<div id='parentDiv'></div>
<button type="button" onclick="addDiv()">Add Div</div>
```

JS

```
function addDiv(){
 var _getParent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
 var _getFirstChild = _getParent.childNodes.length;
 var _createElement = document.createElement('div');
 _createElement.id= "child_"+parseInt(_getFirstChild+1);
 _createElement.classList.add('childElem');
 _createElement.innerHTML="I am child "+parseInt(_getFirstChild+1)
_insertChild(_getParent,_createElement,_getParent.childNodes[0]);
}

function _insertChild(parent,newElem,refElem){
parent.insertBefore(newElem,refElem);

}
```

CSS

```
.childElem{
    background-color:green;
    border-radius:7px;
    width:50;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:5%
```

You can also view a working model [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3sy8wv6d/). Just for demonstration I have used css, which you can avoid or modify accordingly.

Hope this will be useful